# Kendo ui MVC used plugins in the library classes

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My setup is:

- In a library class project
- Using NuGet build environment
- Referencing Kendo UI MVC dll
- Added Web configuration file

Views using a Grid started having this problem. Can't figure out if this is a usage or configuration problem.

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI;

@{
    Html.Kendo().Grid<kendodll.Models.Demo>()
        .Name("demo")
        .Columns(col=>{
            col.Bound(m)
        })
}
```

I should be able to enter a lambda expression for `col.Bound(`, but am unable to do so. I can't finish writing without getting past this issue.

If I create a new empty web project, the same directory structure used is normal, such projects are not normal.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the Nuget package, which does not include the ASP.NET MVC wrappers.

Comment: Kendui the version number 2015.1.408, the new library project, and then use the MVC5 nuget reference, and configure the IntelliSense generates directory changed bin\

Comment: @mmillican Yes, a library project by NUGET reference MVC5 and kendo, if you are creating Web projects, it is normal, but the plugin requires it to be types of projects

Answer (score 2):

You can't get Kendo MVC from NuGet at this moment. You'll need to download the files from the Telerik website and add them to your project.

The [Telerik Kendo UI Q2 roadmap](http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/15-04-07/announcing-the-telerik-kendo-ui-q2-2015-roadmap) says the following:

> **NuGet feed (MVC Server Wrappers)**
>
> In this release cycle we’ll finalize what we started in Q1 and will
> deliver on our promise, i.e. introducing a private NuGet feed for the
> commercial Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC product distribution (secured
> with your Telerik account user/password credentials). Thus you will be
> able to fetch the latest versions or updates of our UI for ASP.NET MVC
> product directly from this NuGet feed, without even visiting
> telerik.com. This is especially useful with .NET 5 and MVC 6, where
> NuGet package management plays a central place for referencing third
> party products in your projects.
>
> Coupling that with our already available (since Q1) Kendo UI Core and
> Professional distributions via Bower, you’ll have a direct access to
> each of our products via these popular package managers.

Telerik Kendo UI 2015 Q2 will be released in July.

[Here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/is-kendo-ui-mvc-nuget-package-available) a Telerik employee says this:

> There's no Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC NuGet package on the public
> NuGet feed. However, you can download such a package from your Telerik
> account's:
>
> Products & Subscriptions > Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC > Download
> Installer and Other Resources > NuGet section
>
> and use it in your project on host it on your private NuGet feed, if
> applicable.

Comment: To clarify slightly, The Kendo UI MVC extensions are a portion of Kendo UI that requires purchase http://www.telerik.com/purchase/kendo-ui so Telerik initially did not put this library into NuGet because then anyone could just easily use it without paying. Last time I looked, only the free portions of Kendo UI were available in NuGet.

Comment: Nuget packages refer to the MVC5,kendoui, I do not have to include js and CSS styles, just need it in the plug-in to normal perception, I view file is an embedded resource.

Comment: Issues like these are generally caused by incorrect configuration/installation. The issue occurs with the MVC wrapper and you mentioned using Nuget. Since MVC wrappers cannot be installed using Nuget, this is likely your issue.

Comment: @Vash I'm sure I configuration problem, because I used in the web project is normal, but I now is needed in the class library project to use automatic sensing is already configured to normal, but col.Bound (m) lamdba input parameters can not be here, now is the question, do not know whether to refer to what